# Find overlapping date range from a data set

Tags: sql, oracle, date, range

```
p_id    book_num conf_num   arrival_dt  departure_dt    create-dt   room_num
353     21807    3328568    19-JUN-15   21-JUN-15       27-JUN-15   2408
353     21807    3328562    18-JUN-15   20-JUN-15       27-JUN-15   2408
```

In the above example arrival_dt and departure_dt is overlapping for 2 different
confirmation numbers for the same room number 2408

also I want to exclude the below set of records where arrival_dt and departure_dt are same

```
p_id    book_num conf_num   arrival_dt  departure_dt    create-dt   room_num
353     21802    3328508    18-JUN-15   21-JUN-15       27-JUN-15   1909    
353     21802    3328555    18-JUN-15   21-JUN-15       27-JUN-15   1909
```

Can you please help me with a SQL logic to find these kind of records in the table

Comment: simple self join. `where parent.arrival_dt between child.arrival_dt and child.departure.dt OR parent.departure_dt between child...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/35d28/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST ( p_id, book_num, conf_num, arrival_dt, departure_dt, create_dt, room_num ) AS
          SELECT 353, 21807, 3328568, DATE '2015-06-19', DATE '2015-06-21', DATE '2015-06-27', 2408 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 353, 21807, 3328562, DATE '2015-06-18', DATE '2015-06-20', DATE '2015-06-27', 2408 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 353, 21802, 3328508, DATE '2015-06-18', DATE '2015-06-21', DATE '2015-06-27', 1909 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 353, 21802, 3328555, DATE '2015-06-18', DATE '2015-06-21', DATE '2015-06-27', 1909 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 353, 21801, 3328444, DATE '2015-06-17', DATE '2015-06-21', DATE '2015-06-27', 2000 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 353, 21801, 3328445, DATE '2015-06-18', DATE '2015-06-20', DATE '2015-06-27', 2000 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 353, 21803, 3328446, DATE '2015-06-19', DATE '2015-06-20', DATE '2015-06-27', 2001 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 353, 21804, 3328447, DATE '2015-06-20', DATE '2015-06-21', DATE '2015-06-27', 2001 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   TEST t
WHERE  EXISTS ( SELECT 'X'
                FROM   TEST x
                WHERE  x.room_num     = t.room_num
                AND    x.arrival_dt   < t.departure_dt
                AND    x.departure_dt > t.arrival_dt
                AND NOT (    x.arrival_dt   = t.arrival_dt
                         AND x.departure_dt = t.departure_dt ) )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/35d28/2/0)**:

```
| P_ID | BOOK_NUM | CONF_NUM |             ARRIVAL_DT |           DEPARTURE_DT |              CREATE_DT | ROOM_NUM |
|------|----------|----------|------------------------|------------------------|------------------------|----------|
|  353 |    21807 |  3328568 | June, 19 2015 00:00:00 | June, 21 2015 00:00:00 | June, 27 2015 00:00:00 |     2408 |
|  353 |    21807 |  3328562 | June, 18 2015 00:00:00 | June, 20 2015 00:00:00 | June, 27 2015 00:00:00 |     2408 |
|  353 |    21801 |  3328444 | June, 17 2015 00:00:00 | June, 21 2015 00:00:00 | June, 27 2015 00:00:00 |     2000 |
|  353 |    21801 |  3328445 | June, 18 2015 00:00:00 | June, 20 2015 00:00:00 | June, 27 2015 00:00:00 |     2000 |
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct logic is that one departs after the other arrivesa and the first arrives before the other departs.  You can do this with a self-join or a `where` clause.

If you just want the records:

```
select r.*
from records r
where exists (select 1
              from records r2
              where r2.pid = r.pid and
                    r2.arrival_dt >= r.departure_dt and
                    r2.departure_dt <= r.arrival_dt
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tbl.*
FROM table tbl
JOIN table tbl1 ON tbl.p_id= tbl1.p_id
WHERE tbl.Arrival_dt <= tbl1.Departure_dt
    AND tbl.Departure_dt >= tbl1.Arrival_dt
```